A sequence problem
Prove that when $n$ is enough large, $a_n\over n$ monotonously increase:
$$a_1=a>0, \ a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{n^2}{a_1+a_2+\cdotp\cdotp\cdotp+a_n}.$$

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

What do you mean by $\frac{\alpha _n}{n} $ ? Please format your expressions in MathJax and provide your thoughts on the topic and extra information.
